# How to convert a Postgres UUID back to human-readable string in Go?

Tags: go, byte

The Go Postgres library defines a type `UUID` [as such](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/ext/gofrs-uuid/uuid.go):

```
type UUID struct {
    UUID   uuid.UUID
    Status pgtype.Status
}

func (dst *UUID) Set(src interface{}) error {
<Remainder Omitted>
```

My code uses this library:

```
import pgtype/uuid

string_uuid := uuid.New().String()
fmt.Println("string_uuid = ", string_uuid)
myUUID := pgtype.UUID{}
err = myUUID.Set(string_uuid)
if err != nil {
    panic()
}
fmt.Println("myUUID.Bytes = ", myUUID.Bytes)
fmt.Println("string(myUUID.Bytes[:]) = ", string(myUUID.Bytes[:]))
```

Here is the output:

```
string_uuid =  abadf98f-4206-4fb0-ab91-e77f4380e4e0
myUUID.Bytes =  [171 173 249 143 66 6 79 176 171 145 231 127 67 128 228 224]
string(myUUID.Bytes[:]) =  ����BO����C���
```

How can I get back to the original human-readable UUID string `abadf98f-4206-4fb0-ab91-e77f4380e4e0` once it is put into `myUUID` which is of type `pgtype.UUID{}`?

Comment: @Reality, there is no such function .String()

Comment: Yes! That's ugly but it works.

Comment: did you try `myUUID.UUID.String()` ?

Answer (score 8):

The code in the question uses the [pgtype.UUID](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype#UUID), not the [gofrs UUID](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype@v1.10.0/ext/gofrs-uuid#UUID) linked from question's prose.

The [pgtype.UUID](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype#UUID) type does not have a method to get the UUID string representation, but it's easy enough to do that in application code:

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("%x-%x-%x-%x-%x", myUUID.Bytes[0:4], myUUID.Bytes[4:6], myUUID.Bytes[6:8], myUUID.Bytes[8:10], myUUID.Bytes[10:16])
```

Do this if you want hex without the dashes:

```
s := fmt.Sprintf("%x", myUUID.Bytes)
```

If the application uses the [gofrs UUID](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype@v1.10.0/ext/gofrs-uuid#UUID), then use:

```
s := myUUID.UUID.String()
```